# Strange error due to misuse of %sysrput in SAS

Tags: sas

I am using AIX 6.1 with SAS 9.1.3
I have a program running in PC SAS 9.1
The program will rsubmit to unix.
Now, I convert the program to be totally running in AIX 6.1
The program fails very strangely.
After investigation, it is due to the %sysrput
Here is a simplified version of the program:

```
options mPrint mLogic symbolGen ; 
%macro combine( startdate= , fullprefix= );
  data _null_ ;   
       call symput( 'plength',compress(length(compress("&fullprefix."))));
  run;  
  data _null_ ;   
       length balance 8. ;  
              balance= 1 + &plength.; 
  run;  
%mEnd;  
data _null_ ;
     call symput( 'refdate', put(today(),date9.));   
run;
%put &refdate.;   
* -- If I forget to comment out the sysrput, the plength cannot be resolved -- ;
%sysrput refdate=&refdate.; 
%put &refdate.;   
%combine( startdate= "&refdate."d, fullprefix=a_filename_prefix );
```

(Sorry that the wordings are not meaningful, I just want to do a demo.)

Actually, in AIX, I should not use %sysrput
I just forget to comment it out.
But, if I forget this, there would be error in the plength macro variable in the balance= statement.  This is very strange.

To solve, simply comment out the %sysrput is ok.

But, does anyone know why the %sysrput will cause failure in a macro variable in the macro ?

Alvin SIU

Comment: Does SYSRPUT give an error when you include it, or does it work?  Does the second %put &refdate. look correct (identical to the first)?

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to tell from your simplified version of your question, but if you are asking why the macro variable `plength` is not present after your macro executes, it is because you must define it as **global** in your macro code itself.  In other words:

```
%macro combine( startdate= , fullprefix= );
%global plength;
...
%mend;
```

And yes, if you use the `%SYSRPUT` command from a SAS session not under control of SAS/CONNECT, you will get a SAS ERROR; and getting a SAS error will put your non-interactive session into "syntax-check" mode, in which case the remaining statements in your program will not execute completely.

This last bit is a common misunderstanding when converting code from a SAS/CONNECT environment to "plain old SAS".  When you use SAS/CONNECT, the "server" side of the connection is started with the "-NOSYNTAXCHECK" option.

Comment: I also think out this syntax check mode hours after the post.  With your comment, I head direct to this direction and finally maybe get the answer.  The whole story is a little bit long and do not have enough char in comment field to tell.  So, I use Answer Your Question, hope that it will have sufficient rooms.  Anyways, thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

After investigation with some little testing. maybe this is the answer.

Actually, I will use OPTIONS ERRORABEND in all batch SAS program to stop the SAS in case of error.  This works for many errors and functions just perfectly.

The %SYSRPUT statement do give out error message saying ... options DMR ...
But the program does not abend stop here.
It does not give any message saying ... OBS=0 ...
It just go on.
So, I just 'think' that this is some minor error just like LIBNAME a non-exist directory and SAS will continue 'normally'.
(BTW, I think that the SYSRPUT error has turn on SYNTAX CHECK mode silently, without any notification nor hint.)

The next %PUT statement is normal, same value as previous one.
This mislead me that the program is running normally.

The next statements are also normal.  There are many SYMBOLGEN, MPRINT and MLOGIC messages.
So, this further mislead me that the program is running very very normally.

After the call symput plength statement, there is a NOTE: Numeric values have been converted ...
This further mislead me the program is running normally.

Until now (after so many look-like normal messages), there is a NOTE saying SAS set option OBS=0 ...
(Maybe this NOTE will appear only after the RUN statement.)

This OBS=0 message is actually the hints which tell SAS is using SYNTAX CHECK mode.
Maybe this OBS=0 is caused by the SYSRPUT error.  But, because there are so many look-like normal messages after the SYSRPUT error, I just overlook this OBS=0 message.
Actually, the call symput is so simply and should not cause any error.
This just further complicate the situation.

As SAS is in SYNTAX CHECK mode, this is why causing the look-like error in the plength variable in the balance statement.

This is the whole story.

Anyway, in order to prevent to enter into this complicated and misleading situation, just remember to comment out all the %SYSRPUT will do.

Comment: This is completely incomprehensible.